# C# waiting for an counter value fails

Tags: c#, locking

I've got a fragment of code that uses a callback to modify counter value from other thread. I'm using lock for it and empty while loop for checking if the counter == 0. It works perfectly when running in Visual Studio. However, after "Releasing" it and running from binary it just freezes. The while loop is presented below, as well as callback method body.

What may be causing it?

Thanks,

```
public void someMethod() {
 //starting a bunch of threads calling the callback method
    while(counter > 0) {}
}

public void Callback()
    {
        lock (this)
        {
            countdown--;
        }
    }
```

Comment: your while loop is outside of a method...

Comment: The callback is run from another thread. This while is a snippet from other method.

Comment: Where is `countdown` intialized? Where is `counter` initialized? Do they relate to each other? Why are you running an empty while? Why not use `Task.AwaitAll`? So many questions...

Comment: Hi Dave, I'm well aware of the Task.AwaitAll. However the specific task at hand was to use lock and counter ;) Servy answer helped me fix it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locks are needed *every time* you access a variable that is shared between threads, not just in one location.  IN this case the code in the `while` loop is not introducing a memory barrier when accessing `counter` and as such the JITter is allowed to make optimizations such as only reading a cached version of the value, or even noticing that the value can't have been written to and so avoiding repeating the read ever.

In this very specific case you could use `Volatile.Read(ref counter)` and it will likely work, however you should be *very* wary of trying to use lock-free or low-lock programming, or even using these low level synchronization primitives.  You should strive to instead use higher level synchronization primitives.  In this specific case a `Semaphore` would be appropriate.  Initialize it to the inverse of the countdown value, release it in the callback, and wait for it in your method.

Locking on the implicit parameter (`this`) is also code smell.  You should strive to only ever lock on objects that are in a very small, rigidly controlled, scope, to avoid deadlocks as a result of locks being taken out on the object from a wide scope of the code base.

Comment: Hi Servy, you were right about the JIT optimizatation. Thank you. I'm aware of the higher level primitives, however the task was to use the synchronized. Thank you for your help